# How to use proc transpose on variables that contain numbers separated with _?

Tags: sas

Hi I am new to sas I have a question regarding proc transpose

**I have this data**

```
Input

School Name      State  School Code    26/07/2009   02/08/2009  09/08/2009  16/08/2009
Northwest High   IL            14556          06       06              06      06
Georgia High     GA            147            05       05              05      06
Macy Hgh         TX            45456          NA       NA              NA      NA
```

The desired output is

```
School Name State   School Code Date    Absent
Northwest High  IL  14566   26/07/2009  6
Northwest High  IL  14556   02/08/2009  6
Northwest High  IL  14556   09/08/2009  6
Northwest High  IL  14556   16/08/2009  6
Georgia High    GA  147     26/07/2009  5
Georgia High    GA  147     02/08/2009  5
Georgia High    GA  147     09/08/2009  5
Georgia High    GA  147     16/08/2009  6
Macy Hgh        TX  45456   26/07/2009  NA
Macy Hgh        TX  45456   02/08/2009  NA
Macy Hgh        TX  45456   09/08/2009  NA
Macy Hgh        TX  45456   16/08/2009  NA
```

**This is the code I have written**

```
proc sort data=work.input;
by School_Name State School_Code;
run;

proc transpose data=work.input out=work.inputModified;
by by School_Name State School_Code;
run
```

I get this error saying that No variables to transpose I think the issue is since the variables are actual numbers like this _26_07_2009 sas does not recognize them,

**But I don't get the desired output the dates are actual variables when imported into sas they become _26_07_2009. Note there are about 185 dates and they are actual variables.**

Thanks

Comment: -1: A very similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722572/how-to-compare-multi-dimension-data-in-sas/21724498#21724498 You need to learn about what are valid SAS names. A valid SAS name does not begin with a number. It also matters how you are importing - post that first.

Comment: well I am importing using proc import datafile then the excel file I cannot change the variables they are dates

Comment: Notice the `NA`s in your file if they  are beining imported as they are then the date variables will be read-in as strings. So you need to first convert all the date variables into numeric by setting `NA` to mean numeric missing value which in SAS is a . (dot)

Comment: But would that work because the dates need to be string format inorder to use proc tranpose.

Comment: That's not true- give it a try and report back. Also read the link I posted above.

Comment: but how would I make all the NA dot cause there are 195 columns that are dates so 185 columns look like this 23/08/2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following transpose does the job:

```
proc transpose data=work.input out=work.inputModified;
by School_Name State School_Code;
var _:;
run;
```

Notice the `_:` notation - it picks up all variables which start with an underscore and transposes them.

As I mentioned in the link in my comments earlier, if you do not explicitly specify the variables you want to tranpose- then `proc transpose` by default looks for numeric variables that are not in the `by` variable list to transpose. However, since your date variables are read-in as strings [due to the presence of `NA`s] it was saying `NOTE: No variables to transpose.`

You can use the following to convert the date and absent columns into numeric columns.

```
data inputModified2;
set inputModified;
format date date9.;
date = input(compress(tranwrd(_name_,'_','')), ddmmyy8.);
if col1 NE 'NA' then absent = input(col1, 8.);
else absent=.;
drop _name_ col1;
run;
```

Comment: okay that worked I am trying it with larger dataset will get back to you